# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'pageSizeOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'

Tags: angular, angular16

I am trying to pass an angular version project that has angular material version 16 and I am encountering this type of error when doing 'ng serve'.

HTML:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="dataSource.data.length" [pageSize]="15" class="paginator" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
            (page)="pageEvent = $event">
</mat-paginator>
```

ts:

```
import { TarjetaModel } from '../../interfaces/tarjeta.interface';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { UntypedFormGroup, UntypedFormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HermanadoService } from './hermanado.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SwalService } from 'app/services/swal.service';
import { TarjetasHermanadas, TarjetasProcesos } from './hermanado.types';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-hermanado',
    templateUrl: './hermanado.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hermanado.component.scss']
})
export class HermanadoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    private unsubscribeAll$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

    displayedColumns         : string[];
    dataSource               : MatTableDataSource<TarjetasProcesos | TarjetasHermanadas>;
    selection                : SelectionModel<TarjetaModel> = new SelectionModel<TarjetaModel>(true, []);
    pageEvent                : PageEvent;
    pageSizeOptions          : number[] = [15, 20, 40, 80, 1000];

Error:

Error: src/app/modules/hermanado/hermanado.component.html:118:92 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'pageSizeOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'pageSizeOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-paginator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

118         <mat-paginator [length]="dataSource.data.length" [pageSize]="15" class="paginator" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
```

Context:
My task is to migrate an angular project that has material to a fuse tamplate, I must transfer my entire project and in the middle I ran into this problem

Note:

I already applied several techniques to solve this problem, for example, importing the MatPaginatorModule module, adding schemas, checking versions and compatibility, I have angular material v16, my version of angular is 16.

Honestly, I tried several things and none of them solved the problem.